# Transaction on the Client Side

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions

i have a big problem to use or understand the use of transaction with wsdualhttpbinding WCF.

i have something like this :

**IService :**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
  //...
  [OperationContract]
  [ApplyDataContractResolver]
  [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)] 
  bool SaveDevice(Device device);
  //...
}
```

**Service.svc.cs :**

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
  public class Service : IService
  {
   [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
   public bool SaveDevice(Device device)
   {
            bool temp = false;
            Transaction transaction = Transaction.Current;

            using (EntityConn context = new EntityConn())
            {
                try
                {
                  //....
                }
             }
    }
   }
```

**Model.cs**
So here im in my Client an try to execute an Operation with Transaction requirements :

```
if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier == Guid.Empty)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
            {
                try
                {
                   //do some stuff
                }
            }
          }
```

Well im getting an Error : Transaction.Current is empty

1. Do i on the right way?
2. When not how can i solve it?

Thank u for helping

**EDIT** : I just needed to place the if after the using

```
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
     if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier == Guid.Empty)
     {
            try
            {
               //do some stuff
            }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Your Service is implementing IService, but your posted code has IVdmService....

Comment: Thanks Tim! its just a mistake!

Comment: Have you set the transactionFlow property in the *both* the service and client bindings (programatically or via config)?

Comment: Yes! both! transactionFlow = true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of a TransactionScope, I think Transaction.Current will always be null.  You need to enter the transaction scope first, then start accessing properties of Transaction.Current.  It looks like you are trying to execute some non-transactional operation at the client?  If so, try this:

```
using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier == Guid.Empty)
    {
        // ambient transaction is not escalated; exclude this operation from the ambient transaction
        using (TransactionScope tran2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ambient transaction is escalated
        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Note: I've copied the condition as you have it in your example code, but you should verify that this is the right test.  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninformation.distributedidentifier.aspx), `TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier` is `null`, not `Guid.Empty`, outside of a distributed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add AutoEnlistTransaction=true on your OperationBehavior attribute.  Likewise, you may want to add AutoCompleteTransaction=true.

Comment: OperationBehavior has just 5 Parameters and none aren't AutoEnlistTransaction!! do i mist something?